# How to initialize an Array in Pascal?

Tags: arrays, initialization, pascal

In Java we can initialize an array by following code:

```
data[10] = {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91};
```

But in Pascal how can we do this?

Comment: [**Don't forget to read the manual for this little things !**](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse23.html)

Answer (score 11):

Here's a full example program that compiles at http://www.onlinecompiler.net/pascal for both Windows and Linux.

```
program test;
var
    data: array[0..9] of integer = (10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91);
begin
    writeln('Hello World');
    writeln(data[0]);
end.
```

Comment: It compiles for me. Remember you must place all declarations **before** begin in Pascal...

Comment: (and what is the compiler?)

Comment: I've edited the answer with a full program plus a link to a compiler.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for Borland Turbo Pascal (nor `fpc -Mtp`)

Comment: This also compiles on two variants of object Pascal that run on the CLR(.Net) which are REMObjects Oxygene and PascalABC.Net.